# Where to insert Vue.productionTip = false in order to get rid of the vue development mode warning

Tags: vue.js

I am a total newbie when it comes to js and all I am trying is to insert that line in order to turn the message off but regardless of where I put it the message stays. My code is

```
var getCalculatorApp = (function () {
    var initialize = function () {      
        new Vue({ 
            el: "#content",
            data: {
                region: "England"
            } //then others stuff and methods
        }); 
    }
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it at the top of your `getCalculatorApp`

```
var getCalculatorApp = (function () {
    Vue.productionTip = false
    var initialize = function () {      
        new Vue({ 
            el: "#content",
            data: {
                region: "England"
            } //then others stuff and methods
        }); 
    }
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
})
```

But to turn off the warning you most likely need to do a production build and that flag doesn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the only thing that turned it off was me downloading and referring to vue min as opposed to vue.